# Angular 5: How to use one form group in different components?

Tags: angular, angular5, angular-forms

The following question is about Angular 5.

I have a form component `MyForm.Form.ts` which is displayed in multiple parent components. However, there are two form controls (let's call them `agency_email` and `delivery_details`), that need to be shown in only two of the parent forms, and need to be validated only if shown. How can this be achieved?

Comment: A form component is instantiated where it is used. If you use the same component in two different places, it is two instances.   They do not interfere with eachother as long as you give it different form groups.

Comment: Ok, but the problem comes from the fact that there is a single form group, representing the form, and inside this group there are controls, that need to be conditionally validated.

Comment: using ngIf to conidtionally show one or the other?

Comment: @EmilAvramov and what is the problem? *Conditionally validated* means you have +1 condition to your validation function....

Answer (score 0):

You have to pass which `form controls` to show from parent. Then in `form` component `OnChange` hook based on input from parent you can update the validations.

Declare a `@Input` in `form` component to catch the available `firmControl`'s to display.

```
@Input() availableOptions: any = {
    agency_email: true,
    delivery_details: true
};
```

Then in `OnChange` based on input update the validations.

```
ngOnChanges(changes: SimpleChanges) {
    if (changes.availableOptions) {
        if (this.availableOptions.agency_email) {
            this.form.get("agency_email").setValidators([Validators.required]);
        } else {
            this.form.get("agency_email").setValidators([]);
        }
        this.form.get("agency_email").updateValueAndValidity();

        if (this.availableOptions.delivery_details) {
            this.form.get("delivery_details").setValidators([Validators.required]);
        } else {
            this.form.get("delivery_details").setValidators([]);
        }
        this.form.get("delivery_details").updateValueAndValidity();
    }
}
```

And use `availableOptions` in `html` to `show/hide` the `formCOntrols`'s.

Here is a [demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-yxwmzc).

Comment: https://imgur.com/a/NxElqVB Here, I made a schematic image to show what I mean. What must be in `MyForm.Form.ts`, so the button to be active?